# Load python request response to tabula.read_pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tabula, tabula-py

I've got a URL that downloads the pdf as response. I want to download the pdf file using python *request* module and want to load the same response in the *tabula* module's function *read_pdf* in order to extract the pdfs from the pdf file. However, I want to do this in memory (without saving in disk) but the *read_pdf* function takes a parameter *input_path* which should be str, path object, or file-like object).
Can anyone suggest a way to convert the response object into a *file-like* object?

**PS**:

1. I've already tried the *io* module's *BytesIO* and *StringIO* but it didn't work.
2. In *tabula* doc it's been mentioned that a URL to a pdf file also but I want to pass some additional parameter in request header along with the proxies which can be easily done with the request module if there is any way to pass all these args in *read_pdf* function that would that do.

Comment: If your response is already a in-memory byte stream, you can pass it to `read_pdf` without any problem; just make sure that the filestream is not already read with `file.seek(0)`.

Comment: @crissal I've tried that as well but it did not work.